# How to optimize a problem using only linear constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex, ampl

I am new to AMPL. Currently I am trying to optimize a networking problem. I can only use CPLEX solver. Others like ILOG CP are forbidden. 
**Input**:

- *Demands* - set of demands that have to be fulfilled (basically QoS rules) which consist of multiple paths between a given pair of servers. Every path must be assigned some guaranteed bandwidth which is >= 0
- *demand_maxPath* - number of paths for a demand *d*
- *hd* - bandwidth requested for a demand *d*

**Goal** 
The goal is to assign bandwidths to every path with regards to some cost function.
Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adviE.png). *d* denotes demand id, *x(d,1)* is a first path that belongs to demand *d* and so on, *hd* denotes bandwidth requested for a demand *d*. 
 
**Constraints**

There are a couple of constraints:

1. sum of bandwidths of all paths for a demand *d* must equal *hd*
2. *x(d,p)* must be equal to *hd*, where *p* is a variable

Constraint 2 enforces that all other paths from a demand *d*, except for path *(x,dp)* must be equal to 0. 
**Approach**

My approach: I declared a variable:

```
var demandPath_signalCount { d in Demands, 1..demand_maxPath[d]}, >= 0;
```

which holds values for each of the paths. The following constraint reflects contraint 1:

```
subject to demand_satisfaction_constraint { d in Demands }:
  sum { dp in 1..demand_maxPath[d] } demandPath_signalCount[d,dp] = h[d];
```

However, I can't think of a way to write constraint 2. For example:

```
subject to path_value_satisfaction_constraint { d in Demands }:
  max { dp in 1..demand_maxPath[d] } demandPath_signalCount[d,dp] = h[d];
```

doesn't work since `max()` function is nonlinear. 
Other idea was to declare another variable:

```
var demand_chosenPath { d in demands }, >= 0;
```

and to use it like so:

```
subject to path_value_satisfaction_constraint { d in Demands }:
  demandPath_signalCount[d,demand_chosenPath[d]] = h[d];
```

It obviously doesn't work either since variables cannot be used as indices. 
Yet another way that I tried was to constraint the values that `demandPath_signalCount` may be equal to like so:

```
set possible_values {d in Demands } = 0..demand_volume[d] by demand_volume[d];
```

and

```
subject to possible_values_satisfaction_constraint { d in Demands, dp in 1..demand_maxPath[d] }:
  demandPath_signalCount[d,dp] in possible_values[d];
```

But then again, the error is: `continuous variable in tuple`

How to formulate the second constraint?

Comment: Use a binary variable such that only one `demandPath_signalCount[d,dp]` can be non-zero.